# Flask untrack .pyc files

Tags: python, flask

I am using [Flask-cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask) to run a web application. It is served with node and npm. However, as I am not really familiar with npm/node I have a problem I cannot fix.

Flask runs good, but at a certain point in the process when I click through the web pages, it detects changes in the .pyc files in different folders. It then restarts and doesn't work properly anymore or even crashes. I tried `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` and the `sys.dont_write_bytecode = true` (and even put it on `false`).

However, nothing works and it keeps tracking the .pyc files in the Anaconda libraries. I even tried to add the `sys.dont_write_bytecode` in the `.bashrc` (and also the anaconda bashrc file alternative- of which I cannot remember the name of).

Then I switched to WinPython and got the exact same problem but then with the .pyc package files of WinPython.

Any other suggestions would be very much appreciated as I ran out of ideas..

Comment: In bash, you need to do `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` to make it part of the exported environment seen by child processes. Also, I think Flask only looks for possible changes in `.pyc` files in debug mode, so turning that off (look up Flask docs for how) would stop it even checking.

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't turn off debug mode as I need it to debug my project. In production mode it indeed doesn't track changes, but that doesn't solve the problem..